# NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

**Hello you!**

I have a problem with v7.AppCombatActivity. It seems that i am to stupid to find the solution, because there are many other postings in www how to fix this, but i can not get it to work. So i think i have to post my problem here to find the solution for my problem.

*Here the Facts:*

My App uses a normal fullscreen-Activity as a Splash-Screen in startup-periode, then i start a new Intent with a AppCombatActivity as Login-Screen. On my Nexus5 is works without a Problem (Android 5.1), but on my Galaxy Tab10.1 it crashes (Android 4.2.2).

```
08-10 11:06:09.530: W/dalvikvm(20561): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5918: Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat;.isAttachedToWindow (Landroid/view/View;)Z
08-10 11:06:09.530: D/dalvikvm(20561): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0025
08-10 11:06:09.553: D/AndroidRuntime(20561): Shutting down VM
08-10 11:06:09.553: W/dalvikvm(20561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41874930)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:796)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:836)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at de.ha.veng.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:81)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-10 11:06:09.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20561):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Constalation:
I have copyed android-support-v7-appcombat to my Workspace and marked as "is Library"
It contains allready the v4.jar, right ?
I added this source to the properties of my project.
Also in my Porject there is a v13 and  i allways get this Warning:

```
WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list.
Because v13 includes v4, using only v13.
```

Is it possible that the v4 is excluded by build, so that appCombat cant access the v4.ViewCombat ??

Here some pics:

The Workspace

[image: the Workspace]

The V7

[image: v7 Properties]

[image: v7 Build Path]

[image: v7 Order an Export]

The App

[image: App Properties]

[image: App Build Path]

[image: App Order an Export]

Please help me! Thanks a lot!

Torsten

(I am not a native english speaker)

Comment: Switch to android studio

Comment: use the jar files from your latest sdk and don't copy it from other libraries and clean it and run.I meant for support v4

Comment: i allready use the latest sdk version i have now linked the v7-appcombat again and clean the project, then run. The same problem.

Comment: @intelliJ Amiya: I just testet the import to Android Sudio. When i run the App i get the error: multiple dex files.... Where can i found the Properties/ buildpath? .... do you have any idea how to learn Android Studio in less than 10 days?

Comment: multiple dex  means when duplicate library presents in your app

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78574/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-android-studio--mobile-22958

Comment: thanx, i know what it means....

Comment: I have the same issue only in the Samsung Phones ..

Comment: I had solved it, as I have copied all the libraries from the SDK folder in the project folder. then changed all references on the Build Path and then clean.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to Android Studio cant be the solution at all. I will switch, but not yet, not on the half way of my project. Next Project, OK. I have a deadline and can not hold it if i now start to learn how Android Studio works.

To mark an answer "switch to Android" as "helpfull" i can not understand.

By the way .... I have solved my posted problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using ecllipse which has limitations .Just switch to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/tools/studio/index.html).[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/sdk/index.html) has become increasingly popular across Android developers and the open source community — so much, in fact, that many users are even moving away from Eclipse entirely.

### [Eclipse is dead for Android development](https://www.airpair.com/android/android-studio-vs-eclipse)

**What Should you do**

[Migrate](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/sdk/installing/migrate.html) to Android Studio.For step by step approach you may visit [Getting Started with Android Studio](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-android-studio--mobile-22958) And [Android Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78574/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1).I hope it helps you a lot